# Recover overwritten partition table of LUKS drive

Tags: data-recovery, luks

I decided to edit the question fundamentally as I found out what happend.
So long story short:
Attempted to format an sdcard with the LUKS drive connected, but closed.
(following [1])
I had some trouble getting it to work and at one point I obviously (bash_history) issued
`sudo parted -s /dev/sdb mklabel gpt` with `/dev/sdb` being the LUKS drive.
The drive now shows as `/dev/sdb` only.

So do I have any chance to recover the origin partition table? I am sure the device had only one partition covering the complete drive.

Many thanks in advance
Leo
[1]: [How to create a mkfs.ext4 file system on an SD card that can be written to by anyone?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650901/how-to-create-a-mkfs-ext4-file-system-on-an-sd-card-that-can-be-written-to-by-an)

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would seem that you are working from two different accounts. Please check the [help page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge these before editing your post.